# How the ensure the critical point of nonconvex function is isolated?

Tags: non-convex-optimization

Let $f: \mathbf{R^n} \to \mathbf{R}$ be differentiable, nonconvex function. The gradient descent iteration is given by
$$x^{k+1} = x^{k} - t_k \nabla f(x^k)$$
To ensure $\lim_{k \to \infty} x^k$ exists, one condition for $f$ is that the critical point of $f$ is isolated, see paper http://proceedings.mlr.press/v49/lee16.pdf. The critical point is defined as $\left\{x\in \mathbf{R}^n : \nabla f(x) = 0\right\}$. A critical point $x$ is isolated if there is a neighborhood $U$ around $x$, and $x$ is the only critical point in $U$.

This condition is new to me. How to understand this condition? What type of function satisfies the isolate critical points condition?

Comment: Are you looking for examples of functions that have critical points that are not isolated?  What about functions that are bounded below but have no critical point?

Comment: Think of one dimensional examples, $\sin$, $\exp$ (which has no critical points). There is no easy classification of functions satisfying the isolated condition, it is a convenience for purposes of proof.

Comment: I want to use this condition, but I do not know how to verify it. Some good examples would help me to understand this condition. @Brian Borcher

Comment: Yes. It looks like the isolated critical point condition is not easy to verify. @ copper.hat